# NeuroSky Mindwave Music Visualizer with Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a final project for school (art school not computer science) where I'd like to make a live visualizer from brainwaves using a NeuroSky Mindwave brain reader and Unity. Unfortunately the teacher has very limited knowledge of coding as well and has left me in a very bad position...

I've built a music visualizer following this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELLANEFw5B8

And also found an example Unity project which can live read and display raw data from the brainwave reader:
https://github.com/tgraupmann/unity_neurosky

**Where I'm stuck is in trying to change the input of my visualizer to be the raw brainwave data rather than music.**

Is someone able to help me move forward with this project? I've already looked at NeuroSky's Unity integration page and emailed them with no success.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks so much!

**Audio Spectrum Visualizer Code**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Spectrum : MonoBehaviour {

// Use this for initialization
public GameObject prefab;
public int numberOfObjects = 20;
public float radius = 5f;
public GameObject[] cubes;

void Start()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfObjects; i++)
    {
        float angle = i * Mathf.PI * 2 / numberOfObjects;
        Vector3 pos = new Vector3(Mathf.Cos(angle), 0, Mathf.Sin(angle)) * radius;
        Instantiate(prefab, pos, Quaternion.identity);
    }
    cubes = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("cubes");
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    float[] spectrum = AudioListener.GetSpectrumData (1024, 0, FFTWindow.Hamming);
    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfObjects; i++)
    {
        Vector3 previousScale = cubes[i].transform.localScale;
        previousScale.y = Mathf.Lerp (previousScale.y, spectrum[i] * 40, Time.deltaTime * 30);
        cubes[i].transform.localScale = previousScale;
    }       
  }
}
```

**ThinkGear Connector Controller Code**
*(as far as I know the file that causes the raw data to be displayed in Unity like the screenshot commented below)*

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using MindWave.LitJson;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace MindWave
{
public class TGCConnectionController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private TcpClient client;
    private Stream stream;
    private byte[] buffer;

    public delegate void UpdateIntValueDelegate(int value);

    public delegate void UpdateFloatValueDelegate(float value);

    public event UpdateIntValueDelegate UpdatePoorSignalEvent;
    public event UpdateIntValueDelegate UpdateAttentionEvent;
    public event UpdateIntValueDelegate UpdateMeditationEvent;
    public event UpdateIntValueDelegate UpdateRawdataEvent;
    public event UpdateIntValueDelegate UpdateBlinkEvent;

    public event UpdateFloatValueDelegate UpdateDeltaEvent;
    public event UpdateFloatValueDelegate UpdateThetaEvent;
    public event UpdateFloatValueDelegate UpdateLowAlphaEvent;
    public event UpdateFloatValueDelegate UpdateHighAlphaEvent;
    public event UpdateFloatValueDelegate UpdateLowBetaEvent;
    public event UpdateFloatValueDelegate UpdateHighBetaEvent;
    public event UpdateFloatValueDelegate UpdateLowGammaEvent;
    public event UpdateFloatValueDelegate UpdateHighGammaEvent;

    private bool m_waitForExit = true;

    private void Start()
    {
        ThreadStart ts = new ThreadStart(Connect);
        Thread thread = new Thread(ts);
        thread.Start();
    }

    public void Disconnect()
    {
        stream.Close();
    }

    public void Connect()
    {
        client = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 13854);
        stream = client.GetStream();
        buffer = new byte[1024];
        byte[] myWriteBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(@"{""enableRawOutput"": true, ""format"": ""Json""}");
        stream.Write(myWriteBuffer, 0, myWriteBuffer.Length);

        while (m_waitForExit)
        {
            ParseData();
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }

    public class PowerData
    {
        public float delta = 0;
        public float theta = 0;
        public float lowAlpha = 0;
        public float highAlpha = 0;
        public float lowBeta = 0;
        public float highBeta = 0;
        public float lowGamma = 0;
        public float highGamma = 0;
        public PowerData()
        {
        }
    }

    public class SenseData
    {
        public int attention = 0;
        public int meditation = 0;
        public PowerData eegPower = null;
        public SenseData()
        {
        }
    }

    public class PackatData
    {
        public string status = string.Empty;
        public int poorSignalLevel = 0;
        public int rawEeg = 0;
        public int blinkStrength = 0;
        public SenseData eSense = null;
        public PackatData()
        {
        }
    }

    int GetObjectCount(String json)
    {
        int level = 0;
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < json.Length; ++i)
        {
            if (json[i].Equals('{'))
            {
                if (level == 0)
                {
                    ++count;
                }
                ++level;
            }
            if (json[i].Equals('}'))
            {
                --level;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    private void ParseData()
    {
        if (stream.CanRead)
        {
            try
            {
                int bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                List<PackatData> packets = new List<PackatData>();

                String packet = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(packet))
                {
                    Debug.Log(packet);
                    if (packet.Contains("}"))
                    {
                        int count = GetObjectCount(packet);
                        if (count == 1)
                        {
                            PackatData data = JsonMapper.ToObject<PackatData>(packet);
                            packets.Add(data);
                        }
                        else if (count > 1)
                        {
                            PackatData[] data = JsonMapper.ToObject<PackatData[]>(packet);
                            for (int index = 0; index < data.Length; ++index)
                            {
                                packets.Add(data[index]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                foreach (PackatData data in packets)
                {
                    if (null == data)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (data.poorSignalLevel != 0)
                    {
                        Debug.Log("data.poorSignalLevel: " + data.poorSignalLevel);
                        if (null != UpdatePoorSignalEvent)
                        {
                            UpdatePoorSignalEvent.Invoke(data.poorSignalLevel);
                        }

                        if (null != data.eSense)
                        {
                            if (UpdateAttentionEvent != null)
                            {
                                UpdateAttentionEvent(data.eSense.attention);
                            }
                            if (UpdateMeditationEvent != null)
                            {
                                UpdateMeditationEvent(data.eSense.meditation);
                            }

                            if (null != data.eSense.eegPower)
                            {
                                if (UpdateDeltaEvent != null)
                                {
                                    UpdateDeltaEvent(data.eSense.eegPower.delta);
                                }
                                if (UpdateThetaEvent != null)
                                {
                                    UpdateThetaEvent(data.eSense.eegPower.theta);
                                }
                                if (UpdateLowAlphaEvent != null)
                                {
                                    UpdateLowAlphaEvent(data.eSense.eegPower.lowAlpha);
                                }
                                if (UpdateHighAlphaEvent != null)
                                {
                                    UpdateHighAlphaEvent(data.eSense.eegPower.highAlpha);
                                }
                                if (UpdateLowBetaEvent != null)
                                {
                                    UpdateLowBetaEvent(data.eSense.eegPower.lowBeta);
                                }
                                if (UpdateHighBetaEvent != null)
                                {
                                    UpdateHighBetaEvent(data.eSense.eegPower.highBeta);
                                }
                                if (UpdateLowGammaEvent != null)
                                {
                                    UpdateLowGammaEvent(data.eSense.eegPower.lowGamma);
                                }
                                if (UpdateHighGammaEvent != null)
                                {
                                    UpdateHighGammaEvent(data.eSense.eegPower.highGamma);
                                }
                            }


                        }
                    }
                    else if (data.rawEeg != 0)
                    {
                        if (null != UpdateRawdataEvent)
                        {
                            UpdateRawdataEvent(data.rawEeg);
                        }
                    }
                    else if (data.blinkStrength != 0)
                    {
                        if (null != UpdateRawdataEvent)
                        {
                            UpdateBlinkEvent(data.blinkStrength);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                Debug.Log("IOException " + e);
            }
            catch (System.Exception e)
            {
                Debug.Log("Exception " + e);
            }
        }

    } // end ParseData

    void OnDisable()
    {
        m_waitForExit = false;
        Disconnect();
    }

    private void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        m_waitForExit = false;
        Disconnect();
    }


}
}
```

Comment: [Screenshot of raw data from ThinkGear Connector Controller in Unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFq1Z.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed the signal processing natural of this problem. Brainwave (if it's Beta wave) has relatively low frequency range, which is about 15 Hz to 30 Hz. Music, on the other hand is audible tone, whose frequency range is between 20 Hz to 20,000 Hz.

I am not familiar with the implementation of this particular visualizer you mentioned here, but if it's implemented as what visualizer suppose to do, the brainwave should show only show some small activity (depends on the amplitude of the brainwave signal) in the lowest frequency range in the spectrum.

There is a potential hack to fix the problem. Usually a visualizer will use [FFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) to transform a time series signal to its frequency domain, during which it will determine the frequency range the operation is performed over. If you can locate the code in the visualizer and change the frequency range to, say 1 Hz to 100 Hz, you should see a proper frequency spectrum.

Comment: Thanks for the input! The only code the visualizer uses is attached above. I was looking to replicate the [brainwave visualizing program](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZF-JQGJ26P0) that NeuroSky made for the scanner but using this Unity music visualizer as the form. So in the end you would be visualizing your brainwaves in 3D (while listening to music, your brain makes the music visualizer). Would you be able to help me pinpoint the specific code to change the input of the visualizer to the live brainwave data instead of audio?

Comment: As far as I can tell in the code, the culprit is in this line **float[] spectrum = AudioListener.GetSpectrumData (1024, 0, FFTWindow.Hamming);**. You should be able to find more about it in documentation from the vendor.

Comment: Great, I had thought so as well but the part I'm really needing help in is finding the proper output code from the brainwave connector controller code. What would I replace this audio line with to replace the input to the brainwaves?

Comment: I don't think there is enough information provided in this question to solve what you mentioned, and frankly I am afraid this might be beyond the purpose of stackoverflow (see [community guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: Sorry for that, I was trying to keep it brief but I still believe StackOverflow is a good place for this. What more information could I provide to help?

Comment: I think the biggest missing link is the how the brainwave data is used. The *ThinkGear Connector Controller Code* imports brainwave data and exports it to a stream, but Unity *AudioListener.GetSpectrumData* process data from an audio channel. The types of the data are different in nature, and there is no clear indication how to reconcile/bridge this. I understand this is part of the problem itself, but there is little to push forward before it's figured out.